# Ubuntu Eclipse 3.8 Vaadin Plugin uninstallable

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, plugins, vaadin

I am trying around for a couple of hours now. I am trying to install the Vaadin plugin (vaadin.com) for eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04. I installed eclipse via Software Center and by downloading an archive from the download page for eclipse. Trying to install the plugin I get the error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3/plugins/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar.
http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3/plugins/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar
Artifact not found: http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3/features/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar.
http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3/features/com.vaadin.integration.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar
Artifact not found: http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3/plugins/com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar.
http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3/plugins/com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar
```

I cannot understand why I get this error, since I am easily able to download those jars manually (if this is a way to solve my problem please tell me how, since I could not find that out either).

Btw I tried Eclipse 3.8 and 3.5, nothing newer, since 3.8 is supposed to be the latest completely working version that works on Ubuntu.

Also, I tried the following links to install the Vaadin Plugin from:

- http://vaadin.com/eclipse
- same and /3.5 and /4.3
- and all of the above with https://

They all give the same error.

If I uncheck the option "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" as suggested on other posts, the install exits with this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 2.3.2.201503060752 (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.feature.group 2.3.2.201503060752)
  Missing requirement: Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 2.3.2.201503060752 (com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.feature.group 2.3.2.201503060752) requires 'org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: 3.8 is not the latest version for Ubuntu. It may be the latest in the official repositories but they are always rather out of date. Direct downloads of the current version from eclipse.org should work.

Comment: I am aware of this fact. I read that all releases after 3.8 are unstable on Ubuntu though, hence I did not bother trying with those. Once I am able to i will try to do it with 4.3 too though, but I don't expect anything to change. I will post the results then.

Comment: Eclipse 4.3 doesn't seem to work with Java - the plugin is installable though. But obviously not usable without working with Java...

Comment: Later versions of Eclipse require Java 7 or even better Java 8.

Comment: I am using OpenJDK 1.7

Comment: I still haven't gotten it to work. For some reason my eclipse doesn't find any JDK, and so I am not able to use it. Any ideas?